# Error loading syntax file, CoffeeScript.tmLangauge, after upgrade to 2.0.1

Tags: coffeescript, textmate, sublimetext, sublimetext2, textmatebundles

[image: SublimeText error message when starting program]

I've already tried `Package Control: Remove Pacakage` and then installing it again. The `CoffeeScript.tmLanguage` **should** be as normal. Anyone else experiencing this? How can it be fixed?

Here is the whole [CoffeeScript.tmLanguage](http://pastie.org/4270481).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solved:**
Turns out, the plugin changed the location of its `CoffeeScript.tmLanguage` file. All you have to do is to `View -> Syntax ->` and then select anything but CoffeeScript, and then simply switch back to CoffeeScript again. Sublime Text will figure out the new location.

Comment: Had the same problem on OSX today (July 18 2012) and I can confirm your solution works on that platform too. I suppose this could have been avoided by the developers btw, but glad there's an easy fix.